# javac is not recognised as internal or external command

Tags: java, path, environment-variables, java-home

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31
PATH = %JAVA_HOME%\bin;
CLASSPATH=%JAVA_HOME%\lib;.;
```

In cmd, `java -version` is working fine but `javac` is not. It is giving error.

Comment: Can you echo %JAVA_HOME% and what is the output of `java -version`?

Comment: Knowing the error would be helpful! ;-). Would you post the error message, please.

Comment: Do not add `%JAVA_HOME%\lib` to your classpath.

Comment: C:\>echo %java_home%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31

C:\>java -version
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\>echo %path%
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;E:\app\SH259935\product\11.2
.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windo
ws\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin;

C:\>javac
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>

Answer (score 0):

You need the syntax `set JAVA_HOME=[path]`
(with no spaces)

If it's a Linux/Unix shell then `JAVA_HOME=[path]`

Try this

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31
echo %JAVA_HOME%
PATH = %JAVA_HOME%\bin;
echo %PATH%
```

Possible explanation for this behaviour: you have a JRE 1.8.0_31 somewhere else on your path, this is why `java` is working but not `javac`.